# Data hybrid logarithmic normalization for ANN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, normalization

is it ok to normalize data by using log normalization before trained the ANN model as following:

xn=log(x)

yn=log(y)

then performing min-max normaliztion as following:

xnn=(xn-min)/(max-min)

ynn=(yn-min)/(max-min)

I found that hybrid normalization improved the model a little bit. is it ok to use this normalization?

Comment: "Ok" for what? Why would it not be "ok"? What problem are you trying to solve? One problem that could arise is that the logarithm of a non-positive number is not a real number. Is that the case here, or are your values all positive?

Comment: @Sycorax all the value are postive .. i asked because the common type of normalization are max-min, std-mean, and log and it is new